# 3D rainfall rendering

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, precipitation, 3d-map, local-scene

The following link shows how to render rainfall in a 3D scene using JavaScript in ArcGIS API. I don't have any experience using ArcGIS API thus, is it possible to render precipitation and cloud cover in such a way that I can define their values too?

[Weather visualization](https://community.esri.com/t5/3d-mapping-questions/3d-rainstorm-visualization/td-p/1222493)

Comment: What do you mean with *in such a way that I can define their values too*? Because cloud cover and precipitation value can be defined in `weather` class (both in range 0-1)

Comment: Cloud cover intensity like low, medium and high rendering and precipitation would be in inches again defining the storm intensity.

Comment: Since values are only between 0 and 1, you need to convert cloud cover classes to 0-1 range; same with storm intensity, inches/hour to 0-1. It's a representative feature, so you set the conversion